# Is Console.SetError thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net

Inmidst of a running program which has multiple threads calling Console.Write, can I call Console.SetError to set a new stream? I.e. is this thread-safe?

Background:
I have a program that will run for days non-stop, it does a fair amount of log output to file, and I'd like to have one separate log file for each day so I can delete the oldest files once in a while. The easiest way to do this is, I figured, just check in minutes interval whether a day has passed and if so, just create a new file & assign the stream to Error output. I try to do it when the system was inactive for a while, but no other fancy checks, so it *could* happen that it's in midst of writing to the (old) stream when the swap happens.
(I don't care if an output line gets split in two, but would mind crashes, heh)

MSDN mentions that Console's "I/O operations are thread-safe", but a call to SetError is not an IO operation in my book, and the MSDN page for SetError does not mention this.

Comment: How are you writing to the error stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably throughout your program you'll have various places that you do things something like this:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
}
```

[Talking about whether something is thread safe isn't really meaningful because it means radically different things to different people and in different contexts.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

It's more effective to just talk about things that can and can't happen with your code.

- A string passed to `Console.Error.WriteLine` will be written to *some* stream.  There's no way to have an error message "dropped on the floor" and not written to anywhere.
- The string passed to a call to `WriteLine` will not be written partially to one stream and partially to another.  The entire string will be written to *some* stream, we just don't necessarily know which one if the call is right around the same time as a call to `SetError`.  This is because `Console.Error` is evaluated to a reference first, and then that reference is told to write out a string.  That the variable `Console.Error` is changed to reference another object won't affect the writer that you already have a reference to.
- Strings may be written out to the "old" stream after you change it.  This will happen when the caller has evaluated `Console.Error` into that variable's value (a reference to a text writer) but hasn't actually written to it yet.
- It's also entirely possible for code to grab a reference to `Console.Error`, hold onto it, and continue writing to it.  If this happens in your application rather than having it constantly evaluate `Console.Error` every time the error stream is needed then the old file may continue to be used, possibly long after you've called `SetError` and changed the error stream.
- Multiple calls to `Console.Error.WriteLine` can end up in multiple files.  If it's important for a message to not span multiple files it needs to not evaluate `Console.Error` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, that does clear things up.
Yeah I've read that article about "threadsafe", maybe not completely internalized yet. But also, I think sometimes it can be inferred by context what aspect of "threadsafe" is talked about.
In my case it meant, can anything 'bad' / unexpected happen as a consequence of using multiple threads.
I hadn't thought of the 4th scenario you lined out! But from what I've seen, the code does not do it that way, luckily (3/4 done project now on my desk)

Comment: @user1847129 That's just it though, we *can't* tell from your question whether anything you would consider "bad" could happen when you do this.  We don't know enough about what your program is doing, or what your expectations are of the program.

Answer (score 0):

From this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=VS.100%29.aspx -,you have the answer.A little sippet where what you are asking is defined:

> By default, the value of the In property is a System.IO.TextReader
>   object, and the values of the Out and Error properties are
>   System.IO.TextWriter objects. However, you can set these properties to
>   streams that do not represent the console; for example, you can set
>   these properties to streams that represent files. To redirect the
>   standard input, standard output, or standard error stream, call the
>   SetIn, SetOut, or SetError method, respectively. I/O operations using
>   these streams are synchronized, which means multiple threads can read
>   from, or write to, the streams.